# Java - StringArray in another StringArray with using of AsList

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterator

Despite of searching, I could not solve the problem that I have. I want to look for a `String` array in another `String` array. But this `array.asList` doesn't seem to be working properly, because it must give a `true`. I took only this part of the code to make it comprehensible. Those "if"s must work, that's what I try to achieve.(In paranthesis everything must return a `true` value) Where could be the problem ? I appreciate your help!

```
final Iterator<String[]> sic2 = sections.iterator();
String[] lines = temp.split("\n");
String[] sectionname  ;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { 
    while(sic2.hasNext()) {
        final String[] val2 = sic2.next();  
        //Choping up the long string in parts.
        sectionname=val2[1].split("\\|");

        for (int k=0; k<sectionname.length; k++) {
            if (lines[i].contains("200") && Arrays.asList(lines[i + 1]).contains(sectionname[k]) && lines[i + 2].contains("=")) {
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace("200", "20_"); //do this if the section names are found at the next line of section codes.
                System.out.println(true);
            }

            if (lines[i].contains("200") && Arrays.asList(lines[i]).contains(sectionname[k])    && lines[i + 1].contains("=")) {
                lines[i] = lines[i].replace("200", "20_"); //do this if the section codes and names are in the same line.

            }
        }       
    }
```

EDIT: I believe the main part of the question would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { 
    for (int k=0; k<sectionname.length; k++) {
        if (Arrays.asList(lines[i + 1]).contains(sectionname[k])) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say you "want to look for a `String` array in another `String` array" what do you mean exactly? Do you want to find whether or not `String[] haystack` contains all of the values of `String[] needle`?

Comment: I meant, to search every member of "sectionname" in every member of "lines"

Comment: it seems your requirment is uncear from your question. please tell us input and desired output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd break the problem up a little, as follows:

```
private boolean allWordsAreInEachLine(String[] words, String[] lines) {
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!allWordsAreInLine(words, line)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean allWordsAreInLine(String[] words, String line) {
    for (String word : words) {
        if (!line.contains(word)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then call it like the following:

```
//This is where your code is currently executed
//...
//...
if (allWordsAreInEachLine(sectionNames, lines) {
    //Do whatever you want to do here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you expect here, but please note that since `lines` is a 1-dimensional string array `lines[i+1]` is its element, i.e. a plain string. This means that `Arrays.asList(lines[i+1])` creates a list that contains only one single element `lines[i+1]` and therefore method `contains()` will return `true` only if this element equals to `sectionname[k]`.

Moreover your code is pretty complicated, contains a lot of similar fragments and fragments that are invoked in chain, so it is not so easy to understand what is going on. Separate your long lines and complex conditions to smaller, try to debug your code and find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You have also a problem with your iterator, when your first line is done, it doesn't come back to start so `sic2.hasNext()` will always be `false` and your code will not do anything for i>0

Answer (score 0):

I edited and corrected the answer of Edd whose logic was very great to create. However, it didn't work because it was only returning if the last element is `true or false`.

So here is how a small array could be searched in a larger one.

```
private static boolean allWordsAreInEachLine(String[] words, String[] lines) {
    boolean found=false;
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (allWordsAreInLine(words, line)) {
            found=true; break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

private static boolean allWordsAreInLine(String[] words, String line) {
    boolean found=false;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (line.contains(word)) {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

then calling the functions like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].contains("200") && allWordsAreInLine(words, lines[i+1]) {
        System.out.println("worked!");
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace("200", "20_"); 
    }
}
```